How can I access recovery mode if MacBook boots up to folder with a flashing question mark and the screen is broken, needing an external monitor?
Thanks for looking into this, this one is a bit of a mess.
I have an intel MacBook Pro with a broken screen. The only way I have found to get an external monitor to work is to close the lid as soon as I press on the power button. What I see on the external monitor is a folder with a flashing question mark.
Through my research, my next step should be to start up my Mac in recovery mode in order to get a fresh install etc. This means pressing down on command - R or command - shift - R whilst booting up.
The problem is that I cannot do this since I need to immediately shut the lid. I have tried putting some things on the keys so they are depressed when closing the lid but that has not worked (I suspect the keyboard is deactivated when the lid is closed).
What could my next step possibly be?
PS: This happened because I was formatting Macintosh HD to put in a fresh install. But after deleting Macintosh HD, my laptop turned off before I could go to the next step which was to install the OS.
Thank you.

Try an external keyboard.

A paper clip and 1 or 2 small magnets? Try sliding a paper clip along the left hand side of the screen to find the embedded magnet that the case uses to detect screen is closed. Place small magnet at corresponding place on left side of main body. You may have to do right side too. External keyboard way easier.
